# Do I make my half raster half vector logo in AI or PS?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, logo, file-format

I always make my logos in AI because I want it to be the best quality possible and all proper vector layers. However I have a client who wishes for an image to be used in their logo. So my base and my text are all or could be all vectors but the only thing raster would be that image.

Where do I edit it to get the best result and quality? Do I just copy the vector files as a smart object into my PS doc or do I do it in reverse and add the image into AI?

I actually don't have much or any experience adding images into AI so if somebody could maybe explain a quick do's and don't to help me for future reference that would also be very appreciated...

Comment: I'd have a desire to recreate whatever raster image they wanted as vector. It's possible in most instances. But without knowing the image I can't be definitive.

Comment: @Scott true, that would be the best solution but quite honestly my drawing skills aren't as up to par yet. It's a scanned image of a vintage flower illustration of some sort. Things you get from a site called Graphic Fairy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can approach this in both ways, however, I would use a high-res, flattened out (✝) PSD and/or TIFF format, because:

- it will cover both print and web usage
- it will be less prone to error vs. an AI file with linked or embedded artwork. In my experience AI files are more sensitive to variations in app versions (CC vs CS6 and so on) or in platform (Mac vs PC), sometimes, strange things happen to AI files, especially when moved around between multiple providers, while a PSD/TIFF format tends to be more stable

(✝) With layers merged, but keeping transparency if needed, instead of a flat white background.

Comment: Hello @Lucian, thank you as well for your feedback. It was equally very helpful. To confirm, your suggestion for a PSD and/or TIFF format useage this applies when there is a mix of photos and vectors in any design correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do. I will generally avoid raster stuff in logos, but if there's no way around that, then I will deliver in transparent PSD and TIFF with layers merged.

Comment: This has helped me design a lot clearly today. I was so worried to mix both but my client truly wishes to have this one image file in the logo (though I agree, I generally try to avoid it as well) and so this new information will definitely help me work more smoothly. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of these two apps. In photoshop you can handle your images quite smoothly and your vactors too, they don't get rasterized unless you convert them.

since it contains images so the end-result for online presentation i.e. on website, mobile display would be an image. It can not be an EPS or Scaleable Vector file.

If the logo contains multiple vector based effects and you can not do in PS but want to do in AI, you can go with it. But the same "the end result would be an image file" ... with higher resolution of 450 DPI or may be 600 DPIs.

So there is no any rule to stay stick with one of these tools in such objectives.

Comment: Hello @MFarooqi thank you for your feedback. This has been very helpful! Does the same "rules" apply to print as well? Because this logo is going to be used for a lot of print products like letterheads and name cards etc.

Comment: Yes Eliza, Even the vectors becomes bitmaps when you print them with printers(technically).  300dpi is the ideal printing resolution for letterheads and visiting cards, and large format hoarding boards are printed in lower resolution, 50dpis to max 85dpis for outdoor and 150 max for indoor flex/x-stands. Also the rule of thumb is, you only see things on a certain distance, visiting cards at about 12in, and hoarding boards at min 200feets, (hoarding boards are same like cinema screen, closer you are, harder to see)

Comment: That is true. So I guess on some levels I should worry more about it being a raster if I say want it suddenly to be in a billboard or something to a much larger scale? If I am following your explaination correctly I mean.

Comment: remember, on much larger scales, the width and height should match to the billboards etc... like if billboard is of 30feets x 90feets, you should use document size be the same 360inch or 30feet X 1080inch or 90feet with 85dpis. (no need higher resolution for such big scales.)   secondly, if your design doesn't contain raster content, then vector has no DPIs limit otherwise yes only the image part will definitely be rastered (dont' worry about vector part or fonts, curves etc)

Answer (score -1):

I've been using Affinity Designer and Photo lately, which seems to offer a combination of vector and raster layers using 'personas'.  The closest thing to the old Adobe Fireworks which did a similar thing long ago.

I don't do printing though, so it may or may not be suitable for that.  You could give the trial a go.

Comment: You should put this in comments.

Comment: How is switching to entirely different software a solution? The user states they have Photoshop/Illustrator. Why would Affinity be *better* and justify the cost of an entirely new software package?